# How to trim right two characters from a string/number in Oracle

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, oracle11g, ssrs-2008

I want to only trim the rightmost two characters in a string.

here is the code for the field that I want to trim:

> `ROUND(ifsapp.customer_order_api.get_gross_amt_incl_charges(c.order_no),-2))

for example, if the api call returns 1136, it will round to 1100.  I want the end result to return '11'

I am in SSRS query editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the job

```
SELECT SUBSTR('your string',1,2) FROM dual;
```

or in detail

```
substr(ROUND(ifsapp.customer_order_api.get_gross_amt_incl_charges(c.order_no),-2)),1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your number by 100 to shift the scale, and round the result:

```
ROUND(ifsapp.customer_order_api.get_gross_amt_incl_charges(c.order_no)/100))
```

With some demo values:

```
with t(x) as (
  select 1136 from dual
  union all select 145 from dual
  union all select 98765 from dual
)
select x, round(x/100) as y
from t;

       X        Y
-------- --------
    1136       11
     145        1
   98765      988
```